# ESLint "no-implicit-globals" rule is being ignored

Tags: javascript, eslint, sencha-touch

I'm working with some old Sencha Touch code, written in old-style JavaScript, that I'm trying to clean up. It's too easy with this code to simply misspell a variable and not see the error, because nothing is being flagged as global or undefined.

I'm trying to use ESLint to address this problem. ESLint is effectively finding other problems, like `var` instead of `let` or `const`, `==` instead of `===`, etc. But variables that should be flagged as undeclared or global are being brashly ignored. For example:

```
'use strict';

Ext.define('mycompany.view.blah.blah.blah', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'filterPanel',
    config: {},

    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        console.log(foobar); // <-- Should be considered a disallowed global, or otherwise undeclared.
        this.on('painted', this.onAfterRender, this);
        this.on('hide', this.workorderFilterHidden, this);
```

I'm using the default `.eslintrc` file provided by Visual Studio, with only a few small changes so far. It's a bit long, but I'll include it for reference.

Any idea what I might be missing? I don't see anything in the default rules that would defeat the "no-implicit-globals" rule, and I defined one allowed global (`Ext`) just in case that was necessary to make the rule kick in.

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true // Allows support of JSX, but use of React plugin is required to support React semantics
    }
  },
  // @typescript-eslint/parser is specified as a command line argument
  "plugins": [
    "node",
    "promise",
    "react",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "env": {
    "amd": true,
    "browser": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true, // This enables ES6 global variables AND ES6 syntax
    "worker": true
  },
  "rules": {
    // The below are some, but not all, of the rules from eslint:recommended https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/conf/eslint-recommended.js (all errors set to warning)
    "constructor-super": 1,
    "for-direction": 1,
    "getter-return": 1,
    "no-async-promise-executor": 1,
    "no-case-declarations": 1,
    "no-class-assign": 1,
    "no-compare-neg-zero": 1,
    "no-cond-assign": 1,
    "no-const-assign": 1,
    "no-constant-condition": 1,
    "no-control-regex": 1,
    "no-debugger": 1,
    "no-delete-var": 1,
    "no-dupe-args": 1,
    "no-dupe-class-members": 1,
    "no-dupe-keys": 1,
    "no-duplicate-case": 1,
    "no-empty": 1,
    "no-empty-character-class": 1,
    "no-empty-pattern": 1,
    "no-ex-assign": 1,
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": 1,
    "no-fallthrough": 1,
    "no-func-assign": 1,
    "no-global-assign": "error",
    "no-implicit-globals": "error",
    "no-inner-declarations": 1,
    "no-invalid-regexp": 1,
    "no-misleading-character-class": 1,
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 1,
    "no-new-symbol": 1,
    "no-obj-calls": 1,
    "no-octal": 1,
    "no-prototype-builtins": 1,
    "no-redeclare": 1,
    "no-regex-spaces": 1,
    "no-self-assign": 1,
    "no-shadow-restricted-names": 1,
    "no-sparse-arrays": 1,
    "no-this-before-super": 1,
    "no-unexpected-multiline": 1,
    "no-unreachable": 1,
    "no-unsafe-finally": 1,
    "no-unsafe-negation": 1,
    "no-unused-labels": 1,
    "no-useless-catch": 1,
    "no-useless-escape": 1,
    "no-var": "warn",
    "no-with": 1,
    "require-atomic-updates": 1,
    "require-yield": 1,
    "strict": "warn",
    "use-isnan": 1,
    "valid-typeof": 1,

    // Other rules
    "default-param-last": 1,
    "eqeqeq": ["error", "always", {"null": "ignore"}],

    // The below are some, but not all, of the rules from eslint-plugin-react:recommended https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#recommended (all errors set to warn)
    "react/display-name": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
    "react/no-children-prop": 1,
    "react/no-danger-with-children": 1,
    "react/no-deprecated": 1,
    "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
    "react/no-find-dom-node": 1,
    "react/no-is-mounted": 1,
    "react/no-render-return-value": 1,
    "react/no-string-refs": 1,
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": 1,
    "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
    "react/require-render-return": 1,

    // Some additional React rules
    "react/no-danger": 1,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1
  },

  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [ "*.ts", "*.tsx" ],
      "rules": {
        // The below are all rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint:recommended https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/eslint-recommended.ts (all errors set to warn)
        "getter-return": 0, //Checked by Typescript - ts(2378)
        "no-dupe-args": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(2300)
        "no-dupe-keys": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(1117)
        "no-unreachable": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(7027)
        "valid-typeof": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(2367)
        "no-const-assign": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(2588)
        "no-new-symbol": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(2588)
        "no-this-before-super": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(2376)
        "no-undef": 0, // This is checked by Typescript using the option `strictNullChecks`.
        "no-dupe-class-members": 0, // This is already checked by Typescript.
        "no-redeclare": 0, // This is already checked by Typescript.

        // The below is some, but not all, of the rules from @typescript-eslint/recommended https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/recommended.json (all errors set to warn)
        "@typescript-eslint/adjacent-overload-signatures": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": 1,
        "camelcase": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/class-name-casing": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": 1,
        "no-array-constructor": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-array-constructor": 1,
        "no-empty-function": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-new": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": 1,
        "no-unused-vars": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": 1,
        "no-use-before-define": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/prefer-namespace-keyword": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing": 1,
        "no-var": 1,
        "prefer-const": 1,
        "prefer-rest-params": 1,
        "prefer-spread": 1
      }
    }
  ],
 
   "globals": {
     "Ext": "readonly"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the rule [no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef).

> Disallows the use of undeclared variables unless mentioned in `/*global */` comments.

The most common reason why I've seen this rule being disabled despite being marked as recommended is because it doesn't work well with TypeScript files, where it is not needed anyway (you can read more in [this FAQ](https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/troubleshooting/#i-get-errors-from-the-no-undef-rule-about-global-variables-not-being-defined-even-though-there-are-no-typescript-errors)).

So, for your use case, a possible solution would be enabling the rule only for .js and .jsx files. You already have that rule disables in `"overrides"` > `"rules"`, so all you need to do is enabling it in the general `"rules"` section above:

```json
"no-undef": 1,
```

Note that [`no-implicit-globals`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-implicit-globals) only warns about variables declared in the global scope, not about implicit globals that appear in inner scopes (e.g. in the body of a function).